# Effective Annual Interest Rate (EAIR) in a 12-month loan

Tags: interest-rates

A \$980 loan is paid over 12 months in 12 equal payments of $90 each. What is the loan's EAIR?

> 980/12=81.666…. (monthly principal payment)
>
> 90-81.6666….=8.3333….. (monthly interest payment)
>
> R = 8.33333…../980 = 0.008503=0.8503% (monthly interest rate)
>
> EAIR=[(1+0.008503)^12] -1=0.10695=10.7%

Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 2):

EAIR is the discounting rate, which makes the aggregate Net Present Value (NPV) of 12 90$-payments equal to `980`. Therefore, you need to solve the following equation:

$980=\sum_{i=1}^{12}\frac{90}{1+R*i/12}$

where R is the EAIR. I get $R=19.36\%$.

This is commonly referred to as usury :)

Comment: How did you solve your equation? Also, is the equation in your answer basically discounting each $90 payment back to present value? If so, shouldn't there be an exponent in there somewhere? Thanks.

Comment: yes, discounting each payment back. in excel, you can use solver to work it out.  no exponent there because by banking convention sub-annual discount factors are written as $1/(1+R*T)$

Comment: I can see how you did it in Excel (just tried it). Could you direct me to a source for deriving that equation?

Comment: Also, the question didn't specify who the lender was. If the lender was not a bank, how would the equation change?

Comment: Shouldn't it be $980=\sum_{i=1}^{12}\frac{90}{(1+R/12)^i}$ ? That gives 18.329%

Comment: @AlexC: For periods sub 1yr, where no compounding occurs, using the first formula shown in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discounting, paragraph "Discount factor". If you agree on depositing money at 10% for below 1yr, you will receive back 1+R*T the initial amount.